# Getting time information from string with pandas and datatime in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, pandas, methods, windows-10

I am doing test excersises for summer school and this is my first experience with python.
It is said, that i can get my time information with folowing code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def print_time_range(times):
    print('Time from: {0}, to: {1}'.format(datetime.fromtimestamp(times.min()), datetime.fromtimestamp(times.max())))

train_likes_df = pd.read_csv('train_likes.csv')
print train_likes_df.shape
train_likes_df.head(3)
print_time_range(train_likes_df.time)
```

which will give me the output:

```
Time from: 2014-01-10 17:15:37, to: 2016-02-24 15:15:37.
```

from the time elements similar to this: 1389733974.0.

But i get an Attribute error with pandas, claiming, that there's no such atribute `time`[image: error]
I understand, that `time` is the datatime's method, and must not go with DataFrame, but that's all i understand. How can i make it all work?
[image: CSV file]

Comment: May you add some lines of your csv file, please

Comment: Have just added. Can print it with command window if You need it

Comment: I run the exact code you provide under linux, and I got no error, are you sure that all dependencies are properly installed ? May you add a 'print(type(train_likes_df))' on line 9 then run it and post the value.

Comment: @ASTEFANI  
I succed with the previus excersice, where i had to operate with the data, but not transforming it to a normal data form, so quite sure, the code is the issue. As You can see, i am using MVS on win10

Comment: Which version of pandas is installed ? print(pd.version.version)

Comment: @ASTEFANI Thats very strange, but it gives me a mistake when checking out the version. What could it be? Pip says, he installed pandas correctly. 
error is: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'". I checked other libraries's versions and it worked okay.

Comment: For checking version you can use `print pd.show_versions()`

Comment: @VladislavLadenkov, Yes concerning the AttributeError, that is because I have a different version. could you downgrade to 0.18.0 or a any other more stable versions to double check , or simply reinstall panda ?

Comment: @ASTEFANI I decided to ckeck jezrael's variant first, it is intresting how he has shooted the issue, and then, if that will not work, i will downgrade. Thank You, Stefani)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
print_time_range(train_likes_df.time.dt.time)
```

You need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `unit`:

```
train_likes_df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(train_likes_df['time'], unit='s')
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""user_id,item_id,channel,time
aa,bb,cc,1389733974
aa,bb,cc,1390459377"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
train_likes_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))

print (train_likes_df)
  user_id item_id channel        time
0      aa      bb      cc  1389733974
1      aa      bb      cc  1390459377

train_likes_df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(train_likes_df['time'], unit='s')
print (train_likes_df)
  user_id item_id channel                time
0      aa      bb      cc 2014-01-14 21:12:54
1      aa      bb      cc 2014-01-23 06:42:57

print (train_likes_df.time.dt.time)
0    21:12:54
1    06:42:57
Name: time, dtype: object
```

Your function works nice:

```
from datetime import datetime
def print_time_range(times):
    print ('Time from: {0}, to: {1}'.format(datetime.fromtimestamp(times.min()), datetime.fromtimestamp(times.max())))

print_time_range(train_likes_df.time)
Time from: 2014-01-14 22:12:54, to: 2014-01-23 07:42:57
```

If there is keyerror, maybe there is some space and it is possible check by `print (train_likes_df.columns)` - there is problem in column `time` - there is `space`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""user_id,item_id,channel,time ,test
aa,bb,cc,1389733974,1
aa,bb,cc,1390459377,2"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
train_likes_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))

print (train_likes_df)
  user_id item_id channel       time   test
0      aa      bb      cc  1389733974     1
1      aa      bb      cc  1390459377     2

print (train_likes_df.columns)
Index(['user_id', 'item_id', 'channel', 'time ', 'test'], dtype='object')
```

You can remove spaces by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
train_likes_df.columns = train_likes_df.columns.str.strip()

print (train_likes_df.columns)
Index(['user_id', 'item_id', 'channel', 'time', 'test'], dtype='object')
```

EDIT by file (I add .`head()` for filter only first 5 records for nicer output):

```
import pandas as pd

train_likes_df = pd.read_csv('train_likes.csv')
train_likes_df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(train_likes_df['time'], unit='s')

print (train_likes_df.head())
                            user_id                           item_id  \
0  612d8e8eef05acff3278c061ec10f704  7aa5d00445cb9d61d1739dd0df9a0a88   
1  71a7f1d1be96603971ba66e4a17e845c  5edaf734b432e5cc954a10b59cb97e70   
2  6eaa117728d50265e6b2ac24a80e04ae  8ad97d075fce19c2d182eb2a4539aa1c   
3  5d9db6ab742755197343505bccfad516  aa5f2ca699da42e467e550f9f071fb3f   
4  3000a163610654f1fa181e74136d2d35  8142d0e687c1c7a317ed9673db9f11a4   

                            channel                time  
0  1f0e3dad99908345f7439f8ffabdffc4 2014-01-14 21:12:54  
1  ec5decca5ed3d6b8079e2e7e7bacc9f2 2014-01-23 06:42:57  
2  98f13708210194c475687be6106a3b84 2014-01-30 06:39:23  
3  98f13708210194c475687be6106a3b84 2014-01-30 03:36:17  
4  c74d97b01eae257e44aa9d5bade97baf 2014-02-14 12:30:23  

print (train_likes_df.time.dt.time.head())
0    21:12:54
1    06:42:57
2    06:39:23
3    03:36:17
4    12:30:23
Name: time, dtype: object
```

Comment: I am sorry, but this did not help: got the same error, only with `dt` insted of `time` . Also, tried `.datatime.time`

Comment: Now i have an error: "time is not in the list". 
In fact, those elements in file are just one string element: there is only one column with string elements in it! I loaded whole file line by line, splited it and created 4 lists for each column. Assuming, that i have a list with only time `element`, what should i do transform it to a normal data type?

Comment: Sorry, see last edit - it looks like unix time. Then you can remive parse_dates from read_csv.

Comment: But You use  `train_likes_df['time']` on the right, which You initialize on the left, so, obviusly, I get the "name 'train_likes_df' is not defined" error

Comment: Sorry, i cant understand your instructions in the comment. If it is the notation to the last edit, then it still dont work and says, that "name 'train_likes_df' is not defined

Comment: Sorry. Phone. Use my last edit in answer after `train_likes_df = pd.read_csv('train_likes.csv')`

Comment: Well, now it goes further, and crashed somewhere in panda library ending up with this `"KeyError: 'time'`. I installed it with `pandas` with `pip`, so i dont think the problem is in library

Comment: Please see edit. Maybe there is problem with some space after text `time`. You can check it by `print df.columns` after `read_csv`

Comment: but my version is `0.18.1` (last version of `pandas`) and it works nice.

Comment: Probably a bug in pandas, could you downgrade your version ?

Comment: @ASTEFANI - what is bug? Do you have some problem with my code?

Comment: jezrael : No problem with your code, on my side (under linux) I have got no error when runing @vladislav-ladenkov code ( with pandas 0.13.1 version ) ... jezrael which version of pandas do you use ?

Comment: @ASTEFANI  I use pandas `0.18.1` - last version.

Comment: @jezrael I havent tried yet, i need some time to understand all the information;)

Comment: @VladislavLadenkov - Ok, no problem.

Comment: @jezrael ohhh, this works sooo goood, thank You for your detailed explanation very much!

Comment: @jezrael I am super sorry, but it seems like i have debugged previus module with temp file readed(not actual file) and it still can't recognize the `time` atribute. And i have just checked the excel file, it doesnt seem to have space after it. But still, there is no diffrence between your temp file and actual csv.  I think, i will try downgrade `pandas`, and see what happens:)

Comment: If data are not confidental, you can share it and I try it too.

Comment: @jezrael Of course, that would be an incredible help!
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiLxOn3P5k-whaM5FCteuNit68Bvvw

Comment: @jezrael Exactly, Hm, maybe, i still cant understand something...But debugger stops on the last row if this part:

`import pandas as pd, io`

`train_likes_df = pd.read_csv('train_likes.csv')`

`train_likes_df.columns = train_likes_df.columns.str.strip()`

`train_likes_df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(train_likes_df['time'], unit='s')`
Did I undertand Your edit correctly?

Comment: Hmmm, I use `anaconda` and I think this is the best for python and pandas.  Do you try it? https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install ?

Comment: @jezrael I dont really know, MVS adviced me to intall the most popular environment - it's just "python" or smth.. Dont think it has "anaconda" word in it

Comment: @jezrael and it's again `KeyError: 'time'`

Comment: I always use it and never was problem with it. I think this has to be some problem with IDE. I use solution with number `5` - http://noeticforce.com/best-python-ide-for-programmers-windows-and-mac

Comment: @jezrael Well, thank You very much, I dont think i would try to shoot it any more, will just try to change pandas and that's all ;)

Comment: @jezrael installed `anaconda` and FINALLY it works all right! Thanks!;)

Answer (score 0):

In the first hand your error is relative to the **datetime module** and in the other hand according to github (today) , [pandas *branch 0.18.1*](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/tree/v0.18.1/pandas) is marked with "**BUG: More followups on to_datetime exceptions**, xref #13033 " and the [core](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/tree/v0.18.1/pandas/core) show "**BUG: COMPAT:0.18** (...)".

Apparently it is a bug in your pandas version, it is still possible for you to work in virtual env with another working version of panda (a previous one for example) until bug will be patch.

Best regards

Comment: under windows, and python 3.